# Saving an object: replace changes only

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, pickle, dill

I have a large object (1.5 GB on the disk) that I save via the python module `dill`. I perform lengthy operations on the object and want to save the new state of the object once in a while. However, large parts of the object remain unchanged in the operations, and I would like to overwrite the file only where things have changed.

Is there a relatively simple way (e.g. with some existing module) to achieve this task?

My intuitive solution would be to save the object attributes one by one and rebuild the object from there. Changes could be noted after reading an already saved attribute by comparing its value (e.g. via a hash function) with the respective attribute that is to be saved. Alternatively, I could track which attributes have been changed during an operation.

Is there a package for that? Is there an alternative way?

I am working with python 3.7.

Comment: there's no good way to do this in general. A file is essentially a sequence of bytes, if you change something inside the file, it almost always would require modifying at least everything after it. At least, for pickle.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What about breaking the file up then, i.e. saving the object in some kind of data base or folder?

Comment: OK, think about what is required to modify just a simple text file. Then, think about what would be required for pickle, which is essentially coded instructions on how to re-create your object. The difficulty lies in that your "edits" rarely will fit perfectly back into the sequence of bytes that is a file. At the end of the day, you will likely just have to modify everything after your edit, even if it is just shifting everything.

Comment: You might be able to do something like this if the object can be split up into pieces or chunks, and each of these saved separately. The `pickle` file format (which I think `dill` uses) is not conducive to incremental updating.

Comment: I think this is too broad/vague. Some good points have been made, and I imagine that it will be difficult to find a more specific answer without **far more information** on your program and the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a module that does - to a large extent - what I was looking for.

- Blocks of files are overwritten only if their content has changed.
- Attributes can be saved separately, and this works recursively.

If attributes are not saved separately, it is necessary to pickle the object completely to compare it to an object already present on the file system. However, since writing to the disk is often what makes saving large objects so slow, significant speedups can be gained for large objects. The exact speedup depends on the hardware of the storage medium.

The code contains a method `save_object` that saves any object without overwriting existing identical sections. Furthermore, I have implemented a class `SeparatelySaveable` that can be used as the base class for all objects for which some attributes shall be saved in separate files. Attributes that are instances of `SeparatelySaveable` also will be saved separately automatically. Further attributes that shall be saved separately can be specified via `SeparatelySaveable.set_save_separately`.

Attributes that are saved separately are placed in a folder next to the file to which the original object is saved. These attributes will be saved again only if they have been accessed after they have been saved initially. When the object is loaded, the separate attributes will not be loaded until they are accessed.

The code can be found at the bottom of this answer. The usage is as follows: saving an object without overwriting similar parts works for all objects:

```
save_object(myObject)
```

Saving attributes separately:

```
# defining classes
class MyClass1(SeparatelySaveable):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
        self.attribute1 = value

        # specify that self.attribute shall be 
        # saved separately
        self.set_save_separately('attribute')

class MyClass2(SeparatelySaveable):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()

        # attributes that are instances of 
        # SeparatelySaveable will always be saved separately
        self.attribute2 = MyClass1(value)


# creating objects
myObject1 = MyClass1()
myObject2 = MyClass2()

# Saves myObject1 to fileName1.ext and 
# myObject1.attribute1 to fileName1.arx/attribute1.ext
myObject1.save_object("fileName1", ".ext", ".arx")

# Saves myObject2 to fileName2.ext and 
# myObject2.attribute2 to fileName2.arx/attribute2.ext and
# myObject2.attribute2.attribute1 to fileName2.arx/attribute2.arx/attribute1.ext
myObject1.save_object("fileName2", ".ext", ".arx")

# load myObject2; myObject2.attribute2 will remain unloaded
loadedObject = load_object("fileName2.ext")

# myObject2.attribute1 will be loaded; myObject2.attribute2.attribute1 
# will remain unloaded
loadedObject.attribute2

# Saves loadedObject to fileName2.ext and 
# loadedObject.attribute2 to fileName2.arx/attribute2.ext 
# loadedObject.attribute2.attribute1 will remain untouched
loadedObject.save_object("fileName2", ".ext", ".arx")
```

**The code:**

```
import dill
import os
import io
from itertools import count
from astropy.wcs.docstrings import name

DEFAULT_EXTENSION = ''
"""File name extension used if no extension is specified"""

DEFAULT_FOLDER_EXTENSION = '.arx'
"""Folder name extension used if no extension is specified"""

BLOCKSIZE = 2**20
"""Size of read/write blocks when files are saved"""


def load_object(filename):
    """Load an object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filename : str
        Path to the file

    """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        return dill.load(file)

def save_object(obj, filename, compare=True):
    """Save an object.

    If the object has been saved at the same file earlier, only the parts 
    are overwritten that have changed. Note that an additional attribute 
    at the beginning of the file will 'shift' all data, making it 
    necessary to rewrite the entire file.

    Parameters
    ----------
    obj : object
        Object to be saved
    filename : str
        Path of the file to which the object shall be saved
    compare : bool
        Whether only changed parts shall be overwitten. A value of `True` will
        be beneficial for large files if no/few changes have been made. A 
        value of `False` will be faster for small and strongly changed files.

    """

    if not compare or not os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            dill.dump(obj, file, byref=True)
        return

    stream = io.BytesIO()
    dill.dump(obj, stream, byref=True)
    stream.seek(0)
    buf_obj = stream.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    with open(filename, 'rb+') as file:
        buf_file = file.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        for position in count(0, BLOCKSIZE):
            if not len(buf_obj) > 0:
                file.truncate()
                break
            elif not buf_obj == buf_file:
                file.seek(position)
                file.write(buf_obj)
                if not len(buf_file) > 0:
                    file.write(stream.read())
                    break
            buf_file = file.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            buf_obj = stream.read(BLOCKSIZE)


class SeparatelySaveable():
    def __init__(self, extension=DEFAULT_EXTENSION, 
                 folderExtension=DEFAULT_FOLDER_EXTENSION):
        self.__dumped_attributes = {}
        self.__archived_attributes = {}
        self.extension = extension
        self.folderExtension = folderExtension
        self.__saveables = set()

    def set_save_separately(self, *name):
        self.__saveables.update(name)

    def del_save_separately(self, *name):
        self.__saveables.difference_update(name)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # prevent infinite recursion if object has not been correctly initialized
        if (name == '_SeparatelySaveable__archived_attributes' or 
            name == '_SeparatelySaveable__dumped_attributes'): 
            raise AttributeError('SeparatelySaveable object has not been '
                                 'initialized properly.')

        if name in self.__archived_attributes:
            value = self.__archived_attributes.pop(name)
        elif name in self.__dumped_attributes:
            value = load_object(self.__dumped_attributes.pop(name))
        else:
            raise AttributeError("'" + type(self).__name__ + "' object "
                                 "has no attribute '" + name + "'")
        setattr(self, name, value)
        return value

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        try:
            self.__dumped_attributes.pop(name)
            try:
                super().__delattr__(name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        except KeyError:
            super().__delattr__(name)

    def hasattr(self, name):
        if name in self.__dumped_attributes or name in self.__archived_attributes:
            return True
        else:
            return hasattr(self, name)

    def load_all(self):
        for name in list(self.__archived_attributes):
            getattr(self, name)
        for name in list(self.__dumped_attributes):
            getattr(self, name)

    def save_object(self, fileName, extension=None, folderExtension=None,
                    overwriteChildExtension=False):
        if extension is None:
            extension = self.extension
        if folderExtension is None:
            folderExtension = self.folderExtension

        # account for a possible name change - load all components
        # if necessary; this could be done smarter
        if not (self.__dict__.get('_SeparatelySaveable__fileName', 
                                  None) == fileName
                and self.__dict__.get('_SeparatelySaveable__extension', 
                                      None) == extension
                and self.__dict__.get('_SeparatelySaveable__folderExtension', 
                                      None) == folderExtension
                and self.__dict__.get('_SeparatelySaveable__overwriteChildExtension', 
                                      None) == overwriteChildExtension
                ):
            self.__fileName = fileName
            self.__extension = extension
            self.__folderExtension = folderExtension
            self.__overwriteChildExtension = overwriteChildExtension
            self.load_all()


        # do not save the attributes that had been saved earlier and have not
        # been accessed since
        archived_attributes_tmp = self.__archived_attributes
        self.__archived_attributes = {}

        # save the object
        dumped_attributes_tmp = {}
        saveInFolder = False
        for name, obj in self.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(obj, SeparatelySaveable) or name in self.__saveables:
                if not saveInFolder:
                    folderName = fileName+folderExtension
                    if not os.access(folderName, os.F_OK):
                        os.makedirs(folderName)
                    saveInFolder = True
                partFileName = os.path.join(folderName, name)
                if isinstance(obj, SeparatelySaveable):
                    if overwriteChildExtension:
                        savedFileName = obj.save_object(partFileName, extension, 
                                                        folderExtension,
                                                        overwriteChildExtension)
                    else:
                        savedFileName = obj.save_object(partFileName)
                else:
                    savedFileName = partFileName+extension
                    save_object(obj, savedFileName)
                dumped_attributes_tmp[name] = obj
                self.__dumped_attributes[name] = savedFileName

        for name in dumped_attributes_tmp:
            self.__dict__.pop(name)

        save_object(self, fileName+extension)

        archived_attributes_tmp.update(dumped_attributes_tmp)
        self.__archived_attributes = archived_attributes_tmp

        return fileName+extension
```